# Force language change on focus into terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard, iterm, language

Is there any way of forcing input language set to default one on terminal/iterm focus?

Basically what I want to achieve is setting current keyboard input language to English on switching back from other programs.
Scripting solutions would work as well.

Comment: Can you explain it clearly ?

Comment: Hey, sure.
For example: I'm typing in English in terminal window. Then switching to skype and chat w/ someone in other language. After that I wanna switch back to terminal and continue typing in English, but I need to change language back to English first.
What I want is to switch language into English automatically on using terminal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a in-built preferences settings in iTerm. But you can use the `KeyBoard Maestro` to achieve it. If you don't have then download from the [official site](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/).

1. Open **KeyBoard Mestro**.
2. Create a group in **Groups** section (to hold all your specific automating processes).
3. Now create a macro with the name **Set iTerm Application Language**.

   a. Add **New Trigger** -> **The focussed window** -> **The focussed window changes**

   b. Add another trigger -> **This application** -> Select **iTerm** -> Select **Active** -> Repeating every **1** seconds.

   c. Add **New Action** -> Select **Set KeyBoard Layout** -> Select the keyboard layout (i.e., language preference).

[image: First Macro]

4. Now create another macro with the name **Set Other Application Languages**.

   a. Repeat a in previous macro.

   b. Add another trigger -> **This application** -> Select **Any Application** -> Select **Activates**.

   c. Repeat c from previous macro.

[image: Second Macro]

You are all set. While switching windows between iTerm and others, you can see the keyboard preference icon changing in the top menu bar on the right corner.

**Note :** The keyboard layouts will appear only if they are added in **System Preferences** -> **Language & Region** -> **Input Sources**.
And the names of the macros can be anything. If you wish to deactivate the triggers, disable them by clicking the Tick mark on top-right side.

Comment: have the requirement resolved ?